# How can I get $A\cos(\alpha t)+\sin(\alpha t)$ from $A'e^{i\alpha t}+B'e^{-i\alpha t}$ (solution of ODE with constant coefficient)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let for example the ODE $y''(t)+\alpha ^2y(t)=0$. The caracteristic equation is $r^2+t^2=0$ and thus $r=\pm it$. I know that the general solution can be written as $$A\cos(\alpha t)+B\sin(\alpha t).$$

But since $e^{\pm \alpha t}$ solve the ODE, $$y(t)=Ae^{it}+Be^{-it}$$ solve the equation as well. So I should be able to find $$A'\cos(\alpha t)+B'\sin(\alpha t),$$
form  $$A'e^{i\alpha t}+B'e^{-i\alpha t}\ ?$$

I tried as follow : $$A'e^{i\alpha t}+B'e^{-i\alpha t}=\frac{A'}{\sqrt{A'^2+B'^2}} e^{i\alpha t}+\frac{B'}{\sqrt{A'^2+B'^2}}e^{-i\alpha t}=\cos(\varphi )e^{i\alpha t}+\sin(\varphi )e^{-i\alpha t}=(\sin(\varphi )+\sin(\varphi ))\cos(\alpha t)+i(\cos(\varphi)-\sin(\varphi ) )\sin(\alpha t),$$

but I still have complex coefficient... may be there is an other way ? Because I can't conclude.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to use different symbols for the coefficients,

\begin{eqnarray}
A' e^{i\alpha t} + B' e^{-i\alpha t} &=& A' \left[\cos \alpha t + i \sin \alpha t \right] + B' \left[\cos \alpha t - i \sin \alpha t \right] \\
&=& \underbrace{(A' + B')}_{A''}\cos \alpha t + \underbrace{i(A' - B')}_{B''}\sin \alpha t \\
&=& A'' \cos \alpha t + B''\sin \alpha t
\end{eqnarray}

The thing here is that $A'$ or $B'$ maybe complex themselves, so $A'$ and $B'$ will be real.

Comment: You mean $A''$ and $B''$ will be real no ? How can we prove the fact that $A''$ and $B''$ will be real ?

Comment: @user623855 Yes I mean $A''$ and $B''$, sorry, typo. If you require the coefficients $A''$ and $B''$ to be real you work it backwards: $\Im A' = - \Im B'$ and $\Re A' = \Re B' $, these are the conditions $A', B'$ must follow so that both $A''$ and $B''$ are real